# Hidden field not being passed with dropzone.js in rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, dropzone.js

I'm using dropzone.js to upload several images to my rails app. 
The idea is that those images belong to a **barco** model.
I have already set the models, and I can see that the `barco_id` is being passed via URL.  I pass via the URL the id of the **barco** but I can't get the images to get the `barco_id` attribute. It's like the `hidden_field` is not working...

This is the new view for the images, with `dropzone.js`:

```
<%= form_for(Image.new, html: { multipart: true, class: "dropzone"}) do |f|  %>
  <div class="fallback">

    <%= f.file_field :avatar %><br>
    <%= f.hidden_field :barco_id %>

    <%= f.submit "Upload my Avatar" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Could you provide how your URL looks like? I mean the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got the solution!
It was just that the fallback div should wrap only the avatar field, not the others... Otherwise it ignores the rest of the fields. 
So the final working code:

```
<%= form_for(Image.new, html: { multipart: true, class: "dropzone"}) do |f|  %>
```

```
<%= f.file_field :avatar %><br></div>
<%= f.hidden_field :barco_id %>

<%= f.submit "Upload my Avatar" %>
```

Comment: You're missing some of your code here and your submit button will show if it's not within your fallback div.

Comment: But this did lead me to the correct answer so thank you!